# Building a tree from nodes with only depth and bottom-most children information

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, tree

I'm rewriting an old project. For arcane reasons (legacy corporation database, can't change), tree-shaped data is stored in the database in a peculiar way: each node has two properties defined: node depth, and a list of bottom-most depth child nodes.

How would I handle transforming that to a regular tree? I'm currently at the level where I have a set of all nodes to be placed in the tree, but I'm at a loss now. One thing I thought of is adding the nodes from the deepest level and going up to the root node, but that's a lot of messing with dangling nodes and resizing the tree.

EDIT: Just realised that my method would involve checking every combination of lower-level nodes to find one whose children sum equals to that of the higher-level one. Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the nodes on depth and insert the nodes level by level.

There is only one root (depth 0 or 1, depending on your input), so the first step is easy.

At a generic step, you need to assign each node of the next level to the correct parent. The criterion is simple: the bottom-most children of the child node are a subset of the bottom-most children of the parent. If running time is not an issue, just check each child node against all parent nodes until you find a match. If that is too slow, please add a comment and I will think some more ;-)

Comment: `"just check each child node against all parent nodes"` - why would you want to do this if you can, as you said, just check whether one of the child's ancestors are contained inside the parent's ancestors?

Comment: @Dukeling By parent nodes I mean all nodes of depth `i` and by child nodes all nodes of depth `i+1`. As far as I see, there is no easy way to decide to which parent a child belongs, so you need to try them all and see of which you have the subset.

Comment: Well, you only need to check whether one of the child's ancestors are contained inside the parent's ancestors (as long as nodes are unique, this check is sufficient) (this would be O(n) instead of O(n^2), or O(log n) instead of O(n) if you use sorted lists (in comparison with a native check-all-nodes, i.e. intersection, process)).

Comment: @Dukeling yes, that's all true. But since the OP didn't mention anything about uniqueness of nodes, I didn't use that as granted. On the other hand, if nodes are not unique, the problem might be undecidable.